# How do I slowly short pins 2 and 3 of a phantom powered mic signal?

Tags: mosfet, switches, audio, relay, microphone

Shorting pins 2 and 3 of a microphone signal will mute it and is acceptable for when phantom power is present. I can do this with a regular switch, or a solid state relay. But is there a simple way to do this with something like a MOSFET that I can slowly turn on? The turn on signal would be +5V from a microcontroller. I am not sure how 5V at the gate of a MOSFET and 48V at the source/drain would work, or it there is a specific part that would work well for this?

Comment: Why "slowly"? To prevent "pop"s, for example?

Comment: @RohatKılıç Yes, regular switch or wire works fine. SSR produces clicks.

Comment: Have you tried a MOSFET PV SSR? They'll be relatively slow. You could also roll your own with a coupler and slow down the gate signal.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yes I have. The PV SSR produces clicks. How would I go about making one that I could control better?

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a [photovoltaic-output optocoupler](https://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/e_download/control/relay/photomos/catalog/semi_eng_apv.pdf) and add an R-C between the output and the gates of back-to-back MOSFETs.

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB1oVm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Not sure how well this will work, but it's probably worth a try.

Comment: Would it be the 1uF cap that controls the turn on time for the MOSFET? I tried this with just the MOSFETS like you have them and I think the 5V gate and 48V drain/source messed everything up.

Comment: The PV optocoupler generates its own voltage, and limits at something like 10V. The time constant Rt * 1uF controls the speed, you can try something like 100K.

Comment: Would the voltage it generates be only an ON/OFF state, or could a microcontroller at the opto input be used to vary the voltage at the opto's output, slowly turning on the MOSFETs without the need for the additional components?

Comment: It has a circuit to make it snap off quickly because that’s necessary for the original purpose so that can’t slow the turn-off. I don’t think a DAC on a microcontroller is easier than 2 cheap and tiny SMT parts. You need a resistor at the input of the onto to limit LED current, of course.

Comment: There is already an MCU for other purposes, so it will be driving the switch regardless. So I'm wondering if there's a way I can use the MCU to slow the on/off of the circuit in one way or another. I don't mind additional programming for the application - the slow on/off is most important.

Comment: Maybe you can find or make an opto that doesn't have the snap-off circuit. I don't know of any offhand. With the circuit you could play with the PV MOSFET SSR you said you had.

Comment: I found a lot of items (modules, ic's amps etc) with the search term "voltage control attenuator" and several variations of that. I even found an arduino circuit for an Arduino. I realize what you want to put it on the microphone but if you can put it on the board the fX has a stronger signal and would be easier to work with and less hum.